# Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<undefined>'. - React

Tags: reactjs, select, react-hooks, webhooks, mantine

I have a `SelectInput` that let me choose 1, 2 or 3, and below that, I have a `MultiSelect` (with Mantine library).

I would like to select the number of co-pilots (on the `SelectInput`), and allow the selected number on the `MultiSelect`.

Here is my code :

```
const [maxCopilote, setMaxCopilote] = useState()

<NumberInput
      defaultValue={1}
      max={3}
      min={1}
      required
      placeholder="Number of copilot"
      onChange={(e) => setMaxCopilote(e)}
 />
                                        
<MultiSelect
      data={['Copilote1', 'Copilote2', 'Copilote3']}
      required
      placeholder="Select copilote(s)"
      maxSelectedValues={maxCopilote}
      clearable
/>
```

With this code, I got the error :

```
Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type SetStateAction<undefined>.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<undefined>'.  TS2345
```

How can I get the number I selected, to put it dynamicaly into `maxSelectValues` ?

Thank you

PS : `console.log(e)` onChange in the numberInput, log the selected number correctly

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Declare a type when using `useState`

```js
const [maxCopilote, setMaxCopilote] = useState<number | undefined>(1)
```

Also, you may add a default value

Comment: I'm glad if it was helpfıul